# How to play audio at a specific time in javascript

Tags: javascript, audio

Heres what ive got, but i cant seem to auto update the time?

```
<script>
function updateTime(){
var currentTime = new Date()
var hours = currentTime.getHours()
var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()
}
setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
var audio = new Audio('audio.mp3');`enter code here`
if(minutes === 39){
audio.play();
}
</script>
```

So im trying to create a web app that will play an audio file at a specific time of the day, also is there anyway of stopping the sound at another time? say 5 mins later?

Comment: You have to put the condition inside the interval, and you probably want to check for hours as well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As adeneo's comment states, you need to have the conditional statement within the event function.

The following will call updateTime every second, and if the minute of the day is 39 and it is not playing, it will start playing audio.  It will also call `setTimeout` to stop the audio five minutes later.

Feel free to add the hour within the `if` statement if you like.

```
var audio = new Audio('audio.mp3');

function updateTime(){
  var currentTime = new Date();
  var hours = currentTime.getHours();
  var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();

  if (minutes == 39 && audio.paused) {
     audio.play();
     setTimeout(function() { audtio.pause(); }, 300000);
  }
}

setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

First let me highlight what went wrong with your code.

1. Semi colons were missing at the end of some lines. So please don't forget to place them.
2. The if loop isnt iterative so if u dont put it inside an iterative method like setInterval it will just run at the time of onload.

An answer is already put up so i have written in a different way.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function play(){
    setInterval(function updateTime(){
        var currentTime = new Date();
        var hours = currentTime.getHours();
        var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
        var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
        console.log('minutes');
        var audio = new Audio('audio.mp3');
        if(minutes === 39 && seconds === 0){
            console.log('play');
            audio.play();
            setTimeout(function() { audio.pause(); }, 200000); 
        }
    },1000);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Question is so old but I hope it helps anyone

```js
var audio = new Audio('audio.mp3');
audio.currentTime = 9 // audio starts from 00:09
audio.play()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).